# You might or You might have?

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

I'd like to know whether the following sentences are properly connected as far as tenses are concerned. The first sentence describes past experience, but the second seems to refer to the present or future. Is this correct?

> If you **have** ever **broken** a favorite mug, plate, or bowl, you **have** likely **gone** through several stages of sorrow. You **might** even hopelessly **try** to glue all the pieces back together, but of course, it **doesn’t look** as good as it did before. You **could pay** someone to fix it and make it look new again, but this would cost a lot of money and take too long. Tossing it would be an option, but there is another way. The Japanese art of kintsugi shines with broken pottery.

I'd appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any writing needs *consistency* when it comes to tense. If your intention is for this piece of writing to read as if addressed to one single person (the reader) and to reference any *possible* past experience they had, then you will need to keep referring back to that hypothetical situation.

So:

> You might *have* even *tried* hopelessly to glue all the pieces back together.

However, you could approach this differently - you could begin by hooking the reader in, referring to their possible past experience, and then change direction to speak more generally, for example:

> In such a situation, *you/one* might try hopelessly to glue all the pieces back together.

Comment: Do you mean that if "you might try . . ." is retained, some sort of linking phrase is needed?